# What to implement in my commercial website in order to legally use PrimeNG MIT license?

Tags: license

I'm trying to find some very specific Angular UI components that I can only find in PrimeNG.

I never used it before,  it looks simple enough to implement, the only problem that I'm having is that I tried to read the MIT license and I got confused.

if I want to use the free version of PrimeNG on my commercial website, do I need to add PrimeNG to the thank you page? Currently I don't have a thank you page.. should I create one?

I'm trying to understand what I need to modify on my website to be able to use PrimeNG legally.

Any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

- update

I am trying to understand with the MIT license, what do I exactly need to add to my commercial website (if anything) to legally use the free version of PrimeNG. I tried to read the MIT license agreement and it confused me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community - added more info in the question , i hope it clear things up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of what you must do, the relevant section of the MIT license is just this:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

Your website contains a copy of the Angular component, so this applies to you. Therefore you must take the *exact* copyright notice and permission notice as supplied with the component and include that in your software. Typically, people will do this by having a "third-party licenses" page which includes all the licenses from open source software they are using, but this is not a strict requirement.

Comment: Note, for the MIT license, such a page is not even required. To satisfy the MIT license, it would be sufficient to keep the copyright and license notice intact while minifying the javascript.